# Python Web-Scraping text separated by comma

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

I ran into a challenge when I was trying to scrape a website for data. The website is [here](https://mojracun.incrementum.si/chartv2/public). The data is more of mere texts, separated by commas (Date and price) and I was going to use python to scrape it and save it as csv/xlsx so I can plot them later.

Here is how it looks

[image]

Here is my code and the error that I received:

> ValueError: No tables found!

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
req = Request('https://mojracun.incrementum.si/chartv2/public', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
data = pd.read_html(webpage)
```

How can I scrape the page and after a successful extraction, save it to csv so I can draw charts?

Comment: Thanks James Z for making it more neater!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://mojracun.incrementum.si/chartv2/public"
data = [i.split(",") for i in requests.get(url).text.split("<br>")]
print(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

Output:

```
              0          1
0    2018-12-17   1.000000
1    2018-12-18   1.025792
2    2018-12-19   1.021829
3    2018-12-20   1.035229
4    2018-12-21   1.025792
..          ...        ...
708  2021-02-26  17.799594
709  2021-02-27  17.963089
710  2021-02-28  18.879716
711  2021-03-01  18.351412
712  2021-03-02  19.637481

[713 rows x 2 columns]
```

Or simply dump it to a `.csv`.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url = "https://mojracun.incrementum.si/chartv2/public"
data = [i.split(",") for i in requests.get(url).text.split("<br>")]
pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv("table_data.csv", index=False, header=["Date", "Price"])
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your assistance! Both of these work! Much appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

once used Panda to create a csv, I understand what kind of solution you might find useful

```
texts=webpage.decode('utf-8') if isinstance(texts,bytes) else webpage 

lists=texts.split('<br>')

lists=lists if isinstance(lists,list) else []

df = pd.DataFrame({'column':lists})

# Save to file =)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: sorry for this typo comment, but `dt` to `df` when saving and `texts` isn't defined and you check for the instance of it, maybe replace `texts` with `webpage.decode('utf-8')`, then it works

Comment: kuso.sama , thanks for the tip, let this be a smaller mistake. But respecting the community, I will fix this bug and make the code better. Thank u, kuso.sama)

Comment: Thanks Blay for your assistance!